# Hosted Projects Meta Search Engine

Tags: open-source, search-engine, code-search-engine, project-hosting

With the [myriad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_free_software_hosting_facilities) of sites available like [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/), [github](http://github.com/), [berlios](http://www.berlios.de/), [rubyforge](http://rubyforge.org/) and many others for hosting open-source projects, I've been wondering if there is a specialised search engine out there that catalogues all the projects available on these different sites.

I'm not talking about a search engine to search actual source code like [koders](http://www.koders.com/) or [google codesearch](http://www.google.com/codesearch), but something that catalogues the projects themselves.

An example would be if I was searching for an open source file comparison/merge utility.  I might put "file compare" into this search engine and get a bunch of matching projects back.  I might even be able to narrow the search based on operating system, implementation language, license or other criteria.

The closest I can think of is [freshmeat](http://freshmeat.net/), although in that case project owners have to submit the information to freshmeat, it doesn't spider out the info itself.  [Krugle](http://www.krugle.org/) does have a "Open Source Projects" tab, but whenever I click on it the page reloads, so that's not real helpful...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is http://www.ohloh.net In a wiki-like manner, somebody has to submit a information about a project. Then their crawler takes over and presents data about the project.